# Visual Studio 2019 and DevOps Connections

Tags: visual-studio, devops, visual-studio-2019

I'm using VS 2019 professional, and every day I am forced to reinitialize my connection to DevOps.  I am using this on my laptop.

I am logged into the laptop, the same way I would log into my PC, same credentials everything and never have this issue on my desktop.

Any ideas on what this daily timeout/reset is?

It gets annoying after awhile.

Thanks.